# How to save DataSet after adding data?

Tags: c#, database, dataset

Yes, I know that this questions has been asked at least 5-10 times in here, but I can't for the life of me get any of the methods to save the data.

The idea is to create a new row in table `Companies` in column `Name` (there is only one column) with value "asdf"`.

I've tried combinations of the following:

```
DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.CompaniesTableAdapter adapter = new DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.CompaniesTableAdapter();

DatabaseDataSet ds = new DatabaseDataSet();

adapter.Insert("asdf");
adapter.Fill(ds.Companies);

adapter.Update(ds.Companies);
ds.AcceptChanges();
ds.Companies.AddCompaniesRow("asdf");
ds.Companies.AcceptChanges();
ds.Companies.AddCompaniesRow("asdf");
ds.Companies.Rows[0]["Name"] = "asdf";
adapter.Update(ds.Companies);
```

I'm using C# WPF .NET 4.5.1

It does add the data, but it doesn't save it when I exit the program - I know that it adds data, because if I call this method twice it crashes, because the value is no longer unique.

Here is the `DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters`:

http://pastebin.com/gNsaRFD5

This did not work either:

```
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(global::AliBabaMailer.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Companies (Name) " +
                                             "Values ('string')", myConnection);
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: How are you getting the connection string?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi, do you mean `SqlConnection`? I am not using one, but since the data is successfully added to the database I think it should be able to be saved.

Comment: No I mean the connection string you are passing to your Data adapter... Post that connection string here

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi, this - `SELECT Name FROM dbo.Companies` ? I don't really have any other code written elsewhere

Comment: No dude, this is the sql query; Please post your class `DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters`, edit the question and add the code

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi - here http://pastebin.com/gNsaRFD5 - it's too long to post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so your problem is the Connection String:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString
```

This connection string is of the form:

```
“Data Source=ServerName;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBaseName;Integrated Security=True”
```

The `|DataDirectory|` is usually here:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData
```

When you save the data it is being saved to a database file at `|DataDirectory| location but when you try to view the data using Server Explorer you are trying to view from a database file which is in your project's folder, that is why If you try to save and then view the data on run time it will work fine because then you will be querying the same database you are storing your data into.

**|DataDirectory|:**

`|DataDirectory|` (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string that indicates the path to the database. It eliminates the need to hard-code the full path which leads to several problems as the full path to the database could be serialized in different places. `|DataDirectory|` also makes it easy to share a project and also to deploy an application.

For example, instead of having the following connection string:

```
"Data Source= c:\program files\MyApp\Mydb.sdf"
```

Using `DataDirectory`, you can have the following connection string:

```
“Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf”
```

To set the `DataDirectory` property, call the `AppDomain.SetData` method. If you do not set the `DataDirectory` property, the following default rules will be applied to access the database folder:

- For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.
- For applications that are running under `ClickOnce`, the database folder uses the specific data folder that is created.

[Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce)

**Coding Advice:**

Try to dispose your Command and Connection Objects like this:

```
using(SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(global::AliBabaMailer.Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Companies (Name) " + "Values ('string')", myConnection))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If anybody is wondering I put `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "");` right before `this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();` and it worked.